Drop caps (lettrine) unaligned when using scrartcl
I've wanted to change up the style of my personal notes and I tried to use a drop cap by using the package lettrine, this is my first time doing this. Normally I use the KOMA-script classes, particularly
scrartcl but I get vertically-unaligned text specifically when using this class.
This is the source file:
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\lettrine{D}{etermination.} Stuff just so that this is not empty. Stuff just so that this is not empty.
Stuff just so that this is not empty. Stuff just so that this is not empty. Stuff just so that this is not empty.
Stuff just so that this is not empty. Stuff just so that this is not empty. Stuff just so that this is not empty.
Stuff just so that this is not empty. Stuff just so that this is not empty. Stuff just so that this is not empty.
\end{document}

And I get the following output:

If I change to the article class I get this, which is what I want:

I would like to have the drop cap letter to be aligned with the smallcaps text.
Thanks to all in advance!

please fix your example so it produces the problem and allows people to test answers, don't make everyone fill in ...

Done. I removed all the random text I wrote so that the question wasn't so cluttered.

thanks actually I went with your original (although there is always a danger the mis-alignment is a result o fthe short text) if you use ... you could have shown the output from the input you showed, but bo harm done, it's fine now:-)

latex warns
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <19.22708> not available
(Font)              size <20.74> substituted on input line 6.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <26.09016> not available
(Font)              size <24.88> substituted on input line 6.



You could use \usepackage{lmodern} or if you want computer modern use
\RequirePackage{fix-cm} as the first line, to allow cm at any size.

Thank you! I ended up using \usepackage{newpxtext} and now it looks great.

article uses 10pt as default, but scrartcl uses 11pt. With \documentclass[11pt]{article} you would also have the alignment result of your scrartcl example and similar:
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\lettrine{D}{etermination.} Stuff just so that this is not empty. Stuff just so that this is not empty.
Stuff just so that this is not empty. Stuff just so that this is not empty. Stuff just so that this is not empty.
Stuff just so that this is not empty. Stuff just so that this is not empty. Stuff just so that this is not empty.
Stuff just so that this is not empty. Stuff just so that this is not empty. Stuff just so that this is not empty.
\end{document}

also results in:

So to get the same alignment use the same font size.
But indeed I would prefer using a scalable font as explained in David's answers, e.g.:
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\lettrine{D}{etermination.} Stuff just so that this is not empty. Stuff just so that this is not empty.
Stuff just so that this is not empty. Stuff just so that this is not empty. Stuff just so that this is not empty.
Stuff just so that this is not empty. Stuff just so that this is not empty. Stuff just so that this is not empty.
Stuff just so that this is not empty. Stuff just so that this is not empty. Stuff just so that this is not empty.
\end{document}


